# How is upstart's socket activation used?

Tags: upstart

Upstart has gained the ability to start a process after a socket is accessed, but I found the feature to be poorly documented. How is a socket-activated daemon and upstart config written?

Comment: Checked the (sparse) man pages? [`upstart-socket-bridge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/upstart-socket-bridge.8.html) and the referenced [`socket-event`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/socket-event.7.html) seem relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into an issue where I needed my upstart script to wait for the libvirt-bin socket, as you can't just used `start on started libvirt-bin` because of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/uvtool/+bug/1228210).

Anyway, I ended up making my upstart script like so:

```
start on socket PROTO=unix SOCKET_PATH=/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
task
exec    /data/configureESA.sh
```

Per the [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/socket-event.7.html) referenced by @sr_:

> The  socket  event  is generated by the upstart-socket-bridge(8) daemon
>          when a socket connection is made whose details match the  socket  event
>          condition  and  environment  specified  in  a  jobs start on or stop on
>          stanza.
>
> start on socket PROTO=inet PORT=80 ADDR=127.0.0.1
>
> start on socket PROTO=unix SOCKET_PATH=/var/run/.s.pgsql.1234
>
> start on socket PROTO=unix SOCKET_PATH=@/at/upstart/example